# Android is replacing some of my app icons with alternative ones. How do I stop this

Tags: app-icons

[image: example with Google Maps]

Homtom HT30

The picture shows the icon for Google Maps.
The programs seem to launch fine but the icons are changed.

Comment: Are you using app icon pack or a launcher that changes app icons

Comment: Not deliberately, but that sounds like what has been installed by the manufacturer, Homtom. How can I check?

Comment: I guess you also mean that you are using stock launcher that came with your phone. Install [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) and from it's settings > look and feel> see what the icon pack shows. Also from the 3 dots menu reset and see if it helps. I am not aware of your OEM but don't think it is OEM initiated

Comment: Yes that was it!  Thanks  I'll answer my comment with this info.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the stock launcher 'Launcher3' which was overriding the Google Maps icon (and others).  A different launcher doesn't have this problem, and looks much better.  User 'beeshyams' suggested 'Nova Launcher' but I installed the 'Google Now Launcher'

Thanks 'beeshyams' for the answer.